# Discord.py how to get bot to print out how many members it has? Also, how do I get my bot to get what a user has said?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So, I want my bot to print out the number of members I have in my server. I get this when I try it:

```
Counter Top MTG has this amount of members: <property object at 0xb6a48e14>
```

My code is:

```
@client.command()
async def report():
    x = server.Server.members
    await client.say("`Counter Top MTG has this amount of members: {}`".format(x))
```

My second question:

So, I want to make a report method, and have the user say something like:

```
!report bob cheated in life
```

And it gets that info and pms it to me. I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the context of the command, get the [`Server`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#server) object from that, and then respond with that information:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def report(ctx):
    await client.say("`{0.name} has this amount of members: {0.member_count}`".format(ctx.message.server))
```

To PM yourself, you must first get the [`User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#user) object representing you, and then use [`send_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.send_message)

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def report(ctx, *, message):
    me = await client.get_user_info("Your User ID")
    pm = "{} reported: {}".format(ctx.message.author, message)
    await client.send_message(me, pm)
```

This requires you to know your Discord ID.  Follow [these steps](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-) to obtain it.

Comment: Thank you! How would I get the users name who sent me the report?

Comment: @asdwdwdad `ctx.message.author.name`

Comment: How would I make it so it sends it in the pm?

Comment: And? Im not sure how to do it so it send s it in pm?